# What is the best way to query data from Table if a Table is dependent to itself in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to fetch data like the below:

```
select u.id
from public.user u
where u.reporting_id in (select u.id from public.user u
                         where u.reporting_id = ?)
```

is there any best way of doing same in PostgreSQL

Comment: Don't use the same table alias twice, people will misread.

Comment: What is your data structure? Seems like inner query should return same results. And have you tried join on itself, just use different aliases for each join

Comment: It is unclear why provided way is not good (besides the alias...) So, this question seems to be opinion based ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to achieve.
For listing users 2 levels down from user 9 for example (users who report to users under user 9), your query (aliasing aside) is not only only correct, it's the *best* approach, [easiest to optimize by the planner](https://www.percona.com/blog/sql-optimizations-in-postgresql-in-vs-exists-vs-any-all-vs-join/).

```sql
select u.id
from public.user u
where u.reporting_id in(select id from public.user
                        where reporting_id = 9);
```

If you actually want the entire structure under user 9, dynamically, regardless of how many levels deep it runs, you'll need [recursion](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-RECURSIVE):

```sql
with recursive cte as (
  select reporting_id as super, id as sub
  from public.user where id=9
 union all
  select a.sub as super, b.id as sub
  from cte a left join public.user b on a.sub=b.reporting_id
  where a.sub is not null
) cycle super set is_cycle using path
select * from cte where not is_cycle limit 42;
```

Under the hood, it is not *actually* recursive - it does the job iteratively, re-evaluating the second `select` and attaching more rows in each round until it reaches a point when it finds nothing or hits a limit.

It's always advised that you add that `limit` clause outside to avoid running out of memory if you do something wrong, as well as [`cycle` detection](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-CYCLE) if your structure isn't guarded against loops, where a row can link to itself or a sequence of links can result in a closed loop of relations.

[Demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/c0K-L6fy)

Answer (score -1):

To query data from a self-referencing table in PostgreSQL, you can use a recursive Common Table Expression (CTE) with the WITH RECURSIVE clause. This allows you to traverse the hierarchical structure of the table.

Here's an example of how you could query all employees and their hierarchical structure:

```
WITH RECURSIVE EmployeeHierarchy AS (
SELECT employee_id, manager_id, 
employee_name
FROM employees
WHERE manager_id IS NULL -- Root level 
 employees (those without a manager)

UNION ALL

SELECT e.employee_id, e.manager_id, 
e.employee_name
FROM employees e
JOIN EmployeeHierarchy eh ON e.manager_id = eh.employee_id
)
SELECT * FROM EmployeeHierarchy;
```

This query creates a recursive CTE named EmployeeHierarchy that starts with employees who don't have a manager (manager_id IS NULL) and then recursively joins with employees who have the same manager, continuing the hierarchy. Adjust the column names based on your actual table structure.

Answer (score -1):

Why can't we use self join

```
select u.id
from public.user u
JOIN public.user u2
on u.reporting_id=u2.id
where u2.reporting_id='';
```